# Bar chart wont appear, but x and y axis as well as the title appear

Tags: r

Here is what I have.

```
barplot(table(ordered(cancer$agecat,
c("Younger than 31","31 to 41","42 to 54","55 or Older"))),
main="Ordered Bar Chart of Age Categorie",ylim=c(0,120),
xlab="Number of People In Each Category")
```

This worked before, everything showed up fine but now nothing.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

have a look to the values in `cancer$agecat`, that might be the reason. This is a working example:

```
 barplot(runif(4), names.arg = ordered(c("Younger than 31","31 to 41","42 to 54","55 or Older")),
         main="Ordered Bar Chart of Age Categorie",ylim=c(0,1),
         xlab="Number of People In Each Category")
```

[image]